# adding element to array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'title' => string 'Ireland - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia'
      'url' => string 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ireland'
  1 => 
    array
      'title' => string 'Ireland's home for accommodation, activities.'
      'url' => string 'http://www.ireland.com/'
```

that I want to add a score of 0 to each element. I thought this simple foreach loop would do the trick but...well....it doesn't :/

```
public function setScore($result)
{
    foreach($result as $key)
    {
        $key = array('title', 'url', 'score' => 0);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: you are changing the $key no good or if you really had to do it then use reference i.e. &$key which i believe you do not want in this , may you you need $res = array() and use $res[] = array(....) and then print_r($res)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new array here and do nothing with it:

```
 foreach($result as $key){
     $key = array('title', 'url', 'score' => 0);
 }
```

What you want to do is to modify a reference to existing one:

```
 foreach($result as &$key){  # Note the '&' here
     $key['score'] = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help guys, I think I understand the foreach loop a bit better now.

Answer (score 6):

`foreach` works on a *copy* of the array. You can modify `$key` all you want, it's not going to reflect on the original array.

You can use `$key` **by reference** though, then it'll work as expected:

```
foreach ($result as &$value) {
    $value['score'] = 0;
}
```

**Manual entry:** http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: That answer maybe is bit confusing, since one can't access the array keys by reference. You are actually accessing the arrays value – which is named `$key`. `foreach( $result as $key => &$value )`

Answer (score 2):

Although deceze is right, you can also do this using [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk), like this:

```
array_walk( $result, function( &$el) { $el['score'] = 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to accomplish this.

```
$array = array( array( 'title' => "Ireland - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia", 'url' => "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ireland"), array( 'title' => "Ireland's home for accommodation, activities.", 'url' => "http://www.ireland.com/" ) );

function setScore( $result )
{
    foreach( $result as &$element )
    {
        $element['score'] = 0;
}
    return $result;
}

$array = setScore( $array );

print_r( $array );
```

You could also do:

```
function setScore( &$result )
{...}
```

and then just:

```
setScore( $array );
```